# Pass value through url to google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

```
//I Want to get 2 values through Url. n1 and n2 and pass to getsheetvalues.
function doGet(e) 
{
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Google Secret key').getSheetByName('Google');
    var b1 = sheet.getSheetValues(e.parameters.n1, 23, 1 , e.parameters.n2);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(b1);
)
```

I want to execute this URL in Wordpress and display the result in content. I will appreciate if anybody help!

Comment: Can I ask you about your current issue?

Comment: Yes, I have made google sheets filled with data. I want to access through url.

1. Firstly, i will send parameters through url. To tell the script which specific cell data i want.

2. Secondly, i want to display the result into my WordPress site.

Comment: Actually I want to display the sorted information on my website: https://tiktokcelebrities.com/. I already have all data in columns. I have created custom functions that are creating Html for me in rows. I will fetch that Html code to my desired page through URL parameters. Hope you understand my full situation.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed that your issue had already been resolved. I'm glad for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run your Apps Script code from a 3rd party application (like in your case because it's a webpage made by you), you need to use the [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) and call the [Method: scripts.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run) endpoint.

You can check the [Browser Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/js) to learn how to set and call the API with a practical example. Taking it as a base and the instructions on [how to execute Functions using Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute) I wrote some code to send some parameters to an Apps Script code and return any primitive variable type you want to.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Apps Script API Quickstart</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Google Apps Script API Quickstart</p>

    <!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
    <button id="authorize_button" style="display: none;">Authorize</button>
    <button id="signout_button" style="display: none;">Sign Out</button>

    <pre id="content" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
      var CLIENT_ID = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID';
      var API_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY';

      // Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
      var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://script.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1"];

      // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
      // included, separated by spaces.
      var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects';

      var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize_button');
      var signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout_button');

      /**
       *  On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
       */
      function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
      }

      /**
       *  Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state
       *  listeners.
       */
      function initClient() {
        gapi.client.init({
          apiKey: API_KEY,
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
          scope: SCOPES
        }).then(function () {
          // Listen for sign-in state changes.
          gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

          // Handle the initial sign-in state.
          updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
          authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
          signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
        }, function(error) {
          appendPre(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
        });
      }

      /**
       *  Called when the signed in status changes, to update the UI
       *  appropriately. After a sign-in, the API is called.
       */
      function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
          callAppsScript();
        } else {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }

      /**
       *  Sign in the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
      }

      /**
       *  Sign out the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleSignoutClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
      }

      /**
       * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
       * as its text node. Used to display the results of the API call.
       *
       * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
       */
      function appendPre(message) {
        var pre = document.getElementById('content');
        var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
        pre.appendChild(textContent);
      }

      /**
       * Shows basic usage of the Apps Script API.
       *
       * Call the Apps Script API to create a new script project, upload files
       * to the project, and log the script's URL to the user.
       */
      function callAppsScript() {
        gapi.client.script.scripts.run({
            // Apps Script project id
            scriptId: "your-script-id",
            resource: {
                // Function's name you want to run
                function: "runFromExternalSource",
                // Paramters you want to pass from Wordpress
                parameters: [{"parameter1" : 123, "parameter2": "This is a test"}]
            }
        }).then((resp) => {
          let result = resp.result;
          if (result.error) throw result.error;
          console.log(` This is the result`);
          console.log(result);
        }).catch((error) => {
          // The API encountered a problem.
          return console.log(error);
        });
      }

    </script>

    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
      onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
      onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

A basic Apps Script function for testing would look like this:

```
function runFromExternalSource(event){
  Logger.log(event.parameter1);
  Logger.log(event.parameter2);
  return event;
}
```